# Time zone issue with CSWP

Tags: search, content-search-web-part, timezone

I'm facing an issue with CSWP date filtering. While refining with date (`Publishing Date` and `Expiry Date`) against Current date and time(Using `Today`), I'm not getting the expected results.

Query:
`ContentTypeId:0x0100335EF9B5BA7048499F833D9E1201388F15* RefinableDate00<={Today} RefinableDate01>={Today}`

`Publishing Date` is mapped to `RefinableDate00`  and `Expiry Date` is mapped to `RefinableDate01` but the issue is that `RefinableDate00` and `RefinableDate01` are giving the `UTC` time but `Today` is giving `UTC+5` .

Regional settings are set to `UTC+5`.

Any ideas?